# How do I loop through a single JSON file for each object to appear on Ionic tinder cards?

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I'm following [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-tinder-cards/) on how to build tinder cards for Ionic 2. The tutorial makes use of randomuser.me's API, but I'd like to use my own JSON file.

Below is my typescript file (though I have omitted some snippets of code that are irrelevant), and the bottom-most function is what I have changed to try retrieving my own JSON data, but it is not working properly :( I think there is something wrong with how I'm trying to loop through the array in my JSON file?

```js
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('myswing1') swingStack: SwingStackComponent;
  @ViewChildren('mycards1') swingCards: QueryList<SwingCardComponent>;

  cards: Array<any>;
  stackConfig: StackConfig;
  recentCard: string = '';

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.stackConfig = {
      throwOutConfidence: (offsetX, offsetY, element) => {
        return Math.min(Math.abs(offsetX)/(element.offsetWidth/2),1);
      },
      transform: (element, x, y, r) => {
        this.onItemMove(element, x, y, r);
      },
      throwOutDistance: (d) => {
        return 800;
      }
    };
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.swingStack.throwin.subscribe((event: DragEvent) => {
      event.target.style.background = '#ffffff';
    });

    this.cards = [{email: ''}];
    this.addNewCards(1);
  }

  voteUp(like: boolean) {
    let removedCard = this.cards.pop();
    this.addNewCards(1);
    if (like){
      this.recentCard = 'You liked: ' + removedCard.email;
    } else{
      this.recentCard = 'You disliked: ' + removedCard.email;
    }
  }

  addNewCards(count: number){
    this.http.get('../../assets/data/pics.json').map(data => data.json().results).subscribe(result => {
      for (let val of result){
        for (var count = count; count<pic.length; count++){
          this.cards.push(val);
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I have also tried making individual JSON files for the objects and retrieve it [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lASrz.png), but have also failed. I tried console logging the JSON data to see what it retrieves, but is always only the second object. No card appears in the stack after that.

The output for both methods I did were just a single card and an "undefined" string appearing below the card after swiping it.

I'm new to using Ionic and Typescript, by the way (and I'm sort of rushing), so any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

(also here is what my JSON file looks like, if it helps:)

```js
{
    "pics": [
             {
                "name": "balls",
                "pic": "assets/img/pics/01.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "snowy field",
                "pic": "assets/img/pics/02.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "hotel bedroom",
                "pic": "assets/img/pics/03.png"
            },
            {
                "name": "apartments",
                "pic": "assets/img/pics/04.jpg"
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure to understand what a piece of code is actually doing, before you make the required changes to it.

Here is the code you are using to add new cards:

```
addNewCards(count: number){
    this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=' + count).map(data => data.json().results).subscribe(result => {
        for (let val of result){
            for (var count = count; count<pic.length; count++){
                this.cards.push(val);
            }
        }
     })
}
```

Looking at this code, there are a few things that stand out, which we'll break down into steps:

1. If you want to read your own JSON file, why are you making the request to the randomuser.me API (`this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results' + count)`? Here you should enter the path to your own JSON file (`this.http.get('../../assets/data/pics.json')`.
2. Next, look at what the code does with the results (`.map(data => data.json().results)`). If we take a look at the JSON that is returned from the API (https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1) we see that the actual results are in the "results" section of the response, so `.map(data => data.json().results)` is actually saying: take what was returned, convert it to JSON, and give me the results. Since your JSON file does not have such a "results" section, it doesn't make sense to ask for that part of the file. You could change it to `.map(data => data.json().pics)` to get a list of all the pics.
3. Now I'm assuming you want to add "count" new cards, so if count is 3 you want to add 3 new cards. First note that this works for the API, because it can create infinite results, but if you want to add 10 cards from your own JSON, you will have to make sure that there actually are at least 10 entries in your JSON.
4. Let's look at the actual body of the function, step by step: `for (let val of result){` loops through every entry returned by the request, so for you, it would loop through all pics. Inside this loop, you are then creating a new loop, which has a few different issues on its own (var "count" has the same name as parameter "count", "pic" is not defined anywhere), but even if the loop was correct, you still loop through all results, so you're not filtering out an amount of results. If you make sure that the length of your list of pics is at least the same amount as count, you could do something more like this:

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       this.cards.push(result[i[);
   }
   ```

So in the end that would leave us with:

```
addNewCards(count: number) {
    this.http.get('../../assets/data/pics.json')
    .map(data => data.json().pics)
    .subscribe(result => {
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this.cards.push(result[i]);
        }
    })
}
```

Good luck, and the main lesson here is: understand the code you're using before trying to change it.

Take a look at my [ionic-soundboard project](https://github.com/rkalis/ionic-soundboard) as well to see how I use my own JSON files to populate a list of entries.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, the data from my JSON file is now appearing on the cards! There's still a problem with it, however; every card I swipe only displays the same object. Do you think I will have to drastically change the code to make each object appear on each card that I could swipe?

Comment: Well, when you add a single card with addNewCards(1), you always add the first card in the list. If you want something else to happen you will have to change the loop. For instance, if you want to add a random entry from your JSON file, you could change `this.cards.push(result[i]);` to `this.cards.push(result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)];`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rosco's answer above that fixes my loop, [Disqus user JB](https://disqus.com/by/disqus_AF4C5C6XIs/) has provided a good solution to making each object from the JSON file appear on each card.
The card-stack div and ion-card in the HTML file should be appended like so (*the zIndex and marginTop properties were modified at the end*):

```
<div swing-stack #myswing1 [stackConfig]="stackConfig" (throwoutleft)="voteUp(true)" (throwoutright)="voteUp(false)" id="card-stack" [style.zIndex]="-1000">
<ion-card #mycards1 swing-card *ngFor="let c of cards; trackBy:trackByCards; let i=index;" [style.zIndex]="-1 * i" [style.marginTop]="i === 0 ? '0px' : '12px'">
```

And this for the Typescript file, in the voteUp() function:

```
let removedCard = this.cards.shift();
```

The difference is the use of *shift()* (instead of *pop()*) as this removes the **first** element from the array in the JSON file. And that's it. Thank you Rosco and JB!!

*Note: once you've gone through all the elements in your array it returns to the first element again; it's a endless loop of cards*